# how to properly edit the /etc/environment file?

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables

I'm trying to transfer my end of environment variables .bashrc file to the end of the /etc/environment file.

But every time I change this file can not login on the computer and to undo the changes through the display mode CTRL+ALT+F2, then to save time, I wonder if my configuration is correct before restarting my computer .

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/​"
CLASSPATH="JAVA_HOME/lib/:$CLASSPATH"
PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin/:$PATH"
M2_HOME="/usr/share/maven/"
M2="$M2_HOME/bin"
PATH="$M2:$PATH"
```

I made the changes as root, it is correct the way edited /etc/environment the file?

Answer (score 13):

You cannot reference previously defined variables in the same way as you would do in .bashrc in the /etc/environment. See [this section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables) of the Ubuntu Community Help wiki,

"It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line."

Also have a look at the [following answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149661/pointers-with-syntax-in-etc-environment/149668#149668) regarding syntax examples.

Comment: How to know if the environment variables $JAVA_HOME or $M2_HOME are Variable expansion? For the link you gave me says Variable expansion does not work in /etc/environment.

Comment: I would think that `PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:${HOME}/MyPrograms` would be classified as a _variable expansion_.
The act of expanding an already existing variable with more content, by using the `:`.

Comment: "Variable expansion" means "turning a variable into its contents". This is how bash uses variables. First, bash reads the command and "expands" all variables into their values. Then bash executes the command. "`/etc/environment` does not support variable expansion" means "`/etc/environment` cannot use variables".

Comment: @mattias I think by `:`, you mean `$` for variable expansion? I can't edit a comment tho.